# Need help understanding this lisp function

Tags: javascript, c#

I am having trouble understanding the return line in this function.

I'm creating a parser in C# and found this tutorial (http://lisperator.net/pltut/parser/the-parser) which was written in Javascript. I can't understand the return line of the function

```
function is_punc(ch) {
    var tok = input.peek();
    return tok && tok.type == "punc" && (!ch || tok.value == ch) && tok;
}
```

I believe it will return true if: tok is not null AND its type is punc AND (the char ch is not null OR the value of tok equals ch) AND tok is not null.

If I am reading this right why is he evaluating tok is not null twice.

Comment: The code you've shown is not lisp... It seems to be JS.

Comment: I also can't find the function you've shown here in the link.

Comment: Down near the bottom of the page there is a button marked "Show Code". And your right its Javascript.

Comment: You're right. `tok` doesn't need to be checked twice.

Comment: Your assessment appears correct to me: The final `&& tok` serves no purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not meaningful in this context, but the logical operators in JavaScript work like those in Python and Lisp (the only connection to Lisp in this question).

That is, `a && b` returns `a` if it is "false-y", otherwise it returns `b`.
Similarly, `a || b` returns `a` if it is "truth-y", otherwise it returns `b`.

Examples (from my Firefox console):

```
> "" && 23
< ""
> 0 && 23
< 0
> 1 && 23
< 23
> 1 && "hello"
< "hello"
> "hello" || "world"
< "hello"
> 0 || "world"
< "world"
```

This means that the final `tok` makes the function return the token itself if all the other conditions are truth-y.

Answer (score 0):

You can express boolean logic with more than `true/false`, and some languages exploit this to return more information from boolean operators. For example, in a JS console, you can write the following:

```
> x = 10
10
> (x < 100) && x
10
```

An integer like 10 belongs to the set of *True* values when used in a boolean context. The result is thus 10.
The same happens in Lisp, where `(or (try-first-this) (maybe-that))` evaluates to the first expression that holds true.

In your case the last term is necessary for the function to return the token.